# Post Text on LinkedIn with Authentication in IOS

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I search a lot for post text via Linked In API, but not able to find any good solution.

How can I authenticate user & post my Text on his page?

Any answer will be greatly appreciated!!

**Help me to Solve this**

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this kind of question is always the same: the [official documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/apis) is your best friend. Also there are some ready to use third-party open source library for implementing linkedin authentication. One example is [this](https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI).